# Is Timer accurate enough to not send TimerEvent.TIMER event after delay?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, timer

I have the following code:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 1);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, someListener);
timer.start();
```

Is it guaranteed that TimerEvent.TIMER will be dispatched before or exactly at 3000ms delay (not 3010, 3050 etc)?

My tests show that TimerEvent.TIMER is always dispatched before or exactly at 'delay' ms, but I couldn't find more info about that in the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to read the bit at the very top of the [Timer API docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html)

Comment: @AmyBlankenship It's a _REALLY_ long time ago since I tinkered with frame rates and timers, but if I remember correctly the explanation in the Timer docs is completely outdated and incorrect.

Comment: It might be incomplete, but it's not incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not exact. Time slicing is a surprisingly complex process.

Here's a few resources:

- http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=910
- http://www.craftymind.com/tag/elastic-racetrack/

What it all comes down to in a nut shell, is that the AVM tries to juggle between executing system code, user code and frame rendering as fast as possible, but needs to decide on what process gets which priority (and subsequent processing time) and it's these decisions that will influence timer accuracy. I.e sometimes accurate, sometimes not.

Basically, the more you throw at it, the less accurate it gets.